# File location reference issue in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

When I am adding a new file to the project, the file location is showing with respect to the system. Instead of showing system reference, it has to display only file name(MyViewController.swift).

for your reference, I am adding an image also.
  [image]
s

Please help me to fix this issue. Thank you.